# Carrying forward the summation symbol when differentiating $E = \dfrac{1}{2} \sum (z - t)^2 $?

Tags: derivatives, summation, partial-derivative, error-function

My lecture notes state the following:

> $z = \dfrac{1}{1 + e^{-s}}$
>
> $E = \dfrac{1}{2} \sum (z - t)^2$
>
> $\therefore \dfrac{ \partial{E} }{ \partial{s} } = (z - t)z(1 - z)$

In this case, $E$ is an error function.

I have calculated that $\dfrac{ \partial{E} }{ \partial{s} } = \dfrac{ \partial{E} }{ \partial{z} } \dfrac{ dz }{ ds } = \left[ \sum (z - t) \right]z(1 - z)$

And so I have two questions that I would appreciate clarification on:

1. Am I correct in saying that $\dfrac{ \partial{E} }{ \partial{s} } = \dfrac{ \partial{E} }{ \partial{z} } \dfrac{ dz }{ ds }$?
2. Why doesn't the summation symbol carry forward?

Comment: What you have looks right to me.  I assume the sum is on $t$?

Comment: It is possible that someone made a mistake.  Are these handwritten notes?  Are they *your* handwritten notes? (If yes, you might have forgotten to write something down).  Are these *your professor's* handwritten notes? (If yes, they may have made a mistake, and would probably be grateful for an email seeking clarification and / or correcting a mistake).  Are these type-up notes from somewhere?  (If yes, again, the author would probably appreciate a note indicating that there may be an error).

Comment: @Dzoooks Ahh, That could be it. It is only said that $E$ is half the sum over all input patterns of the square of the difference between actual output and desired output. Besides saying this, $t$ is never formally defined. Anyway, thanks for the response.

Comment: @XanderHenderson These are typed online lecture notes from another university.

Comment: Anyway, as Dzooks said, it could be that the summation is over $t$. Otherwise, it is an error. In any case, there does not seem to be sufficient clarity to discern precisely what’s going on here, so I’ll leave it at that. Thank you all for the assistance.

Comment: @ThePointer  I'll bet it's a typo.

Comment: @Dzoooks okay. Thank you for the assistance.